# Cause of Java Error Stack

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

How do I determine the cause of this error stack

Is it complaining about a missing Jar file ?

Thanks

```
Caught Exception while Creating QueueConnection from QueueConnectionFactory com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSFMQ6312: An exception occurred in the Java(tm) MQI. The Java(tm) MQI has thrown an exception describing the problem. See the linked exception for further information. com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSFMQ6312: An exception occurred in the Java(tm) MQI. The Java(tm) MQI has thrown an exception describing the problem. See the linked exception for further information.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:319)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:233)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6889)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6277)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:285)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6233)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:120)
        at connection.JMSConnection.makeQueueConnectionMQSeries(JMSConnection.java:228)
        at connection.JMSConnection.makeQueueConnection(JMSConnection.java:614)
        at testType.JMS_PTP.setupMsgTransportProtocol(JMS_PTP.java:335)
        at testType.JMS_PTP.run(JMS_PTP.java:806) Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2195;AMQ9546: Error return code received. [1=java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException[null],3=NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0]
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.processESESecurity(JmqiEnvironment.java:989)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getInstance(JmqiEnvironment.java:809)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getMQI(JmqiEnvironment.java:615)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6881)
        ... 8 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.processESESecurity(JmqiEnvironment.java:896)
        ... 11 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/mq/headers/MQDataException
        at com.ibm.mq.ese.service.ServicesFactoryImpl.createPolicyService(ServicesFactoryImpl.java:173)
        at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.InterceptedJmqiImpl.createServices(InterceptedJmqiImpl.java:224)
        at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.InterceptedJmqiImpl.<init>(InterceptedJmqiImpl.java:184)
        at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI.<init>(ESEJMQI.java:117)
        ... 16 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.mq.headers.MQDataException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        ... 20 more Linked Exception: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2195;AMQ9546: Error return code received. [1=java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException[null],3=NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0]
-----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.mq.headers.MQDataException`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is complaining about a missing *class* file. Where that file should be is up to you.

Answer (score 3):

In order to identify the cause of an error in a StackTrace it is common to read the stack **from bottom to up** and look for the **Caused by** words. That is the main reason of your problem. In your particular case:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.mq.headers.MQDataException
```

So that states that this class `MQDataException` was not found on your classpath. So you should put the jar that contain this class on the classpath of your application and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If its a standalone application, just install the WebSphere MQ Client in the location of your choice and add the just a few jars to the classpath as given here: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc%2Fjm10330_.htm . This would be easier I guess.